# Can we set static value at the end of Dropdown list?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I am having two Drop Down list Country and state both list are filled from database. In Drop Down list for states I want to add "Others" at the end of the list. I tried adding "Others" from database but when I use order by Name to show name of states in alphabetic order in my Drop Down List even "Other" gets rearranged but I want to display it at the end of my list.

This is my code how I am populating my list

```
private void FillStateDDl()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] sql = new SqlParameter[2];
        sql[0] = new SqlParameter("@Type", 2);
        sql[1] = new SqlParameter("@cid", drpCountry.SelectedValue);
        ds = gs.DisplayData("sp_FillDropDownList", sql);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            drpState.DataTextField = "statename";
            drpState.DataValueField = "sid";
            drpState.DataSource = ds;
            drpState.DataBind();
            drpState.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select State--", "-1"));
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that you used to populate the drop down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that `AppendDataBoundItems` is set to true.

Then items can be added after the data source like:

```
ddl.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
ddl.DataSource = CreateDataSource();
ddl.DataTextField="TextField";
ddl.DataValueField="ValueField";
ddl.DataBind();
ddl.Items.Add("Static value here....");
```

Comment: Using AppendDataBoundItems Appends the specified value at the end of the list which was working perfect but in my code i have used "drpState.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select State--", "-1"));" so whenever i select a new country "--Select state--" is getting added again and again.

Comment: @Navy It sounds like your appending again on post back. You should wrap the logic in a `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` to prevent this.

Comment: Thanks alot its woking perfect

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set static value with datasource in the dropdown list. You need to do following steps:

1. Select properties of dropdownlist, and find AppendDataBoundItems and set AppendDataBoundItems = true.
2. After binding the dropdown list, add following line of code ddl.Items.Add("Others") in vb.net
3. Also order by in descending order

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can do something like this

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT 1 AS RowId, .... -- Main query
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS RowId, ... -- Include others here 
)
SELECT * FROM C
ORDER BY RowId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
drpState.Items.Insert(drpState.Items.Count - 1, new ListItem("--Select State--", "-1"));
```